# How to inverse match/blacklist with regex?

Tags: regex, shell, unix

I've seen this question: [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

But I can't get it to work. I have a shell script and I'm using

```
string1.*string2.*string3
```

To search for 3 words in a file, in that order. But I want to change it so that if badword5 is anywhere in between those words in that file, there is no regex match with grep.

So this should match:

```
./testing/test.txt:   let prep = "select string1, dog from cat",
          " where apple = 1",
          " and string2 = 2",
          " and grass = 8",
          " and string3 = ?"
```

But this should not:

```
   ./testing/test.txt:   let prep = "select string1, dog from cat",
          " where apple = 1",
          " and string2 = 2",
          " and grass = 8",
          " and badword5 = 4", 
          " and string3 = ?"
```

I unsuccessfully tried:

```
string1((?!badword5)|.)*string2((?!badword5)|.)*string3
```

The entire script:

```
find . -name "$file_to_check" 2>/null | while read $FILE
do
   tr '\n' ' ' <"$FILE" | if grep -q "string1.*string2.*string3"; then echo "$FILE" ; fi
done >> $grep_out
```

Comment: Which unix/shell tool are you using?

Comment: Hi again, you are very helpful. I know that this is a .sh script, and I'm using grep inside of it. Is that enough info? I'm not sure what else to say other than that.

Comment: This needs something much more than `grep -q "word1.*word2.*word3"`
I see if I can come up with something

Comment: Can you please post your script in your question?

Comment: Updated with the script.

Comment: ok provided an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***"To search for 3 words in a file, in that order. But I want to change it so that if badword5 is anywhere in between those words in that file, there is no regex match with grep."***

Indeed, and the search pattern stretches multiple lines.
let's drop `grep` for the moment and try something different:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -name "$file_to_check" 2>/dev/null | while read FILE
do
    SCORE=0
    tr ' ' '\n' <"$FILE" | while read WORD
    do
        case $WORD in
        "word1"    ) [ $SCORE = 0 ] && SCORE=1               ;;
        "word2"    ) [ $SCORE = 1 ] && SCORE=2               ;;
        "word3"    ) [ $SCORE = 2 ] && echo "$FILE" && break ;;
        "badword5" ) SCORE=0                                 ;;
        esac
    done        
done >grep_out
```

the case lines do the following thing:

```
"    word1"      )    [ $SCORE     =       0 ] &&      SCORE  =       1  ;;
when word1 is found: and SCORE is equal to 0 then make SCORE equal to 1
when word2 is found: and SCORE is equal to 1 then make SCORE equal to 2
when word3 is found: and SCORE is equal to 2 then print filename and break out of the inner loop.
```

Comment: if this works for you then I can make one that accepts all the words on the commandline, including "!bad" ones .

Comment: Nice approach! I'm trying it now, it's taking a long time though. I expect it to, since the filesystem is large. I think I can manage to setup the command line arguments myself, though I appreciate the offer. I'm just totally stuck on this search thing.

Comment: when I have to do a fast search on a large filesystem, I always search in stages: a first recursive grep for one of the words, that shortens the list of files a lot. Let's see if I can think of something faster. If I know something I will add it as another answer.

Comment: I think the speed of this alright, actually, but it doesn't seem to be working. Also, are the args to your 'tr' command backwards? I tried it both ways but you had them the other way around in the other thread, and that worked perfectly before.

Comment: No the args are not backwards, this time I replaced every space with a newline to transform the text to a "word list" (one word per line). I will take another look at this script. either I made an error or I didn't fully understand the question.

Comment: Can you explain what each case is doing with the square brackets and the double ampersand? I think I understand what you're doing here, I just don't understand the syntax.

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation :-)  The square brackets are an evaluation (compare), the '&&' means: if previous argument was ok then do next argument.

Comment: btw, i found the error. I made a typo: `/dir1/null` instead of `/dev/null` . I updated the answer, it should be OK now.

Comment: Got it! The problem was that $SCORE was never initialized to 0. It worked with my small test file - now I'm trying the entire filesystem. I will report back when it's done.

Comment: It took about 3 days to scan ~1000 files each at 10k lines long. I'll try your method of searching for general keywords before doing the scoring. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -v` to skip a line for `badword5`:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < "$FILE" | grep -v 'badword5' | if grep -q "string1.*string2.*string3"; then echo "$FILE" ; fi
```

Comment: I thought that using -v wouldn't work, because our search is spanning multiple lines, plus, it would search the entire file for badword5, not just within our pattern. I could be wrong.

Comment: @anubhava: you probably mean `grep -v 'badword5' ||` ... Which wouldn't execute further commands. As far as I understand, any occurrence of badword5 wouldn't match either in between any words or not.